# using partialLoop view helper in controller

Tags: controller, zend-framework2, view-helpers

in my controller i use json model for an "ajax action". In the action i have an array of data entity that i would like to render with "partialLoop view helper"

I use the code listed  below

```
public function addLookuptableAction(){
    try{
        //CUT
        $repositoryModuloLookup = $this->em->getRepository('User\Entity\ModuloLookup');
        $moduloLookUpEnAllArr = $repositoryModuloLookup->findAll();
        $htmlModuleLookUp = $this->createHtmlModuleLookUp($moduloLookUpEnAllArr);
        $o['s'] = 'success';
        $o['i'] = "ok" . $out;
    }catch(\Exception  $e){
        $newExceptionCode = new GetExceptionCode($this);
        $o['s'] = 'error';
        $o['i'] = $newExceptionCode->GetCode($e);;
    }
    return new JsonModel($o);
}

private function createHtmlModuleLookUp($moduloLookUpEnAllArr){
    if(count($moduloLookUpEnAllArr) > 0){
        $partialLoop = $this->getPartialLoop();
        //$partialLoop->setView(new View() );
        $partialLoop('modulo.lookuptbl.tbl.phtml',$moduloLookUpEnAllArr)->setObjectKey('object');
    }
}

private function getPartialLoop(){
    return  new \Zend\View\Helper\PartialLoop();
}
```

but i get the following error code

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function render() on a non-object in D:\www\httpdocs\test\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Helper\Partial.php on line 61
```

the error is clear

is there a way to obtain what i want using vie helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it from the controller's `serviceLocator`. First you have to get the `viewHelperManager`, once you've got it, you could find the `partialLoop`:

```
    $vhm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get( 'viewhelpermanager' );
    $partialLoop = $vhm->get( 'partialloop' );
```

You can get any of these view helpers through the `viewHelperManager`:

```
    'doctype'             => 'Zend\View\Helper\Doctype', // overridden by a factory in ViewHelperManagerFactory
    'basepath'            => 'Zend\View\Helper\BasePath',
    'url'                 => 'Zend\View\Helper\Url',
    'cycle'               => 'Zend\View\Helper\Cycle',
    'declarevars'         => 'Zend\View\Helper\DeclareVars',
    'escapehtml'          => 'Zend\View\Helper\EscapeHtml',
    'escapehtmlattr'      => 'Zend\View\Helper\EscapeHtmlAttr',
    'escapejs'            => 'Zend\View\Helper\EscapeJs',
    'escapecss'           => 'Zend\View\Helper\EscapeCss',
    'escapeurl'           => 'Zend\View\Helper\EscapeUrl',
    'gravatar'            => 'Zend\View\Helper\Gravatar',
    'headlink'            => 'Zend\View\Helper\HeadLink',
    'headmeta'            => 'Zend\View\Helper\HeadMeta',
    'headscript'          => 'Zend\View\Helper\HeadScript',
    'headstyle'           => 'Zend\View\Helper\HeadStyle',
    'headtitle'           => 'Zend\View\Helper\HeadTitle',
    'htmlflash'           => 'Zend\View\Helper\HtmlFlash',
    'htmllist'            => 'Zend\View\Helper\HtmlList',
    'htmlobject'          => 'Zend\View\Helper\HtmlObject',
    'htmlpage'            => 'Zend\View\Helper\HtmlPage',
    'htmlquicktime'       => 'Zend\View\Helper\HtmlQuicktime',
    'inlinescript'        => 'Zend\View\Helper\InlineScript',
    'json'                => 'Zend\View\Helper\Json',
    'layout'              => 'Zend\View\Helper\Layout',
    'paginationcontrol'   => 'Zend\View\Helper\PaginationControl',
    'partialloop'         => 'Zend\View\Helper\PartialLoop',
    'partial'             => 'Zend\View\Helper\Partial',
    'placeholder'         => 'Zend\View\Helper\Placeholder',
    'renderchildmodel'    => 'Zend\View\Helper\RenderChildModel',
    'rendertoplaceholder' => 'Zend\View\Helper\RenderToPlaceholder',
    'serverurl'           => 'Zend\View\Helper\ServerUrl',
    'viewmodel'           => 'Zend\View\Helper\ViewModel',
```

Comment: thanks it works. i add that if you put the partialLoop in an controller's property , as `$this->partialLoop` then when you invoke it you've got an error.

I think this happens because controller class try to initialize an controller's plugin named partialLoop

i Sorry but i can't vote plus one because i have not sufficient reputation on stack overflow. I marked your answer like "correct answer"